# fixnum and prime numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby, math, primes, monkeypatching

Before I set about to writing this myself, has anyone seen a ruby implementation of the following behavior?

```
puts 7.nextprime();     #=>  11
puts 7.previousprime(); #=>  5
puts 7.isprime();       #=> true
```

Obviously this kind of thing would be ugly for large numbers but for integers never exceeding a few thousand (the common instance for me) a sensible implementation is doable, hence the question.

Comment: here's an interesting thread: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/147995

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby comes with a built-in `Prime` class that allows you to iterate through primes starting at 1, but I see no way to initialize it with a starting value other than 1, nor a predicate check to determine whether or not a number is prime. I'd say go for it, though you should keep in mind that math in Ruby can be slow and if performance is a factor you may be better off considering writing it as a C or Java extension. Here's an example of [how to use RubyInline to generate primes in C](http://on-ruby.blogspot.com/2006/07/rubyinline-making-making-things-faster.html).

Also, I suggest you avoid using the method name `7.isprime` - the convention in Ruby is `7.prime?`.

Comment: thanks for the reminder on prime? I usually try to provide aliases using both conventions

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the snippets found [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5380). They could give you a headstart.